# Update table1 with count from table1 when count is null

Tags: mysql

I had a query that `updated` a row in table1 with `COUNT(*)` from another table -

```
UPDATE t1
SET a=(SELECT COUNT(b) FROM t2 WHERE c=10 GROUP BY c))
WHERE id=20
```

The problem is if there are **no entries** in t2 with c=10, the query itself fails as `SELECT` returns **null** or nothing. Is there a way to make this work even if the **sub-select** statement returns null?

**P.S.** I have tried using IFNULL, but looks like that also doesn't work.

Comment: how about a `SELECT COUNT(b) FROM t2 WHERE c=10 GROUP BY c UNION ALL select 0 limit 1` ? i totally just pulled that out of my a** so let me know

Comment: Thanks @Gillyspy, eggyal's solution worked, so going with it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of MySQL's many curiosities is that, if one drops the `GROUP BY` clause (MySQL will implicitly group all rows if an aggregate function is used in the absence of an explicit `GROUP BY` clause), it will always return aggregated results even if there are no underlying records; in the case of the `COUNT()` function, it returns a result of 0 as desired:

```
UPDATE t1 SET a=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2 WHERE c=10) WHERE id=20
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca046/1/0).

Comment: if you could make your answer more directly relevant to the question it would help.  SO is all about the answers connecting the dots, not only creating more dots

Comment: @gillyspy: I fail to see how this answer is not directly relevant to the question.  It even includes an explicit example of corrected code.  Grateful for your suggested improvements.

Comment: i can see it now that you fiddled it.  it used "it" so often i forgot what it was trying to say about it.  +1 for it.

Comment: @gillyspy: I'm rolling back your edit because it changed the meaning of my post; in your revision, the sentence "this is because..." apparently attempts to explain the curious behaviour, which is not what I had intended - rather, it was an explanation of why removing the `GROUP BY` clause does not result in an error (as it would in other RDBMS).

Comment: Thanks a lot @eggyal , That totally resolved it and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

control null value by IFNULL :

```
    UPDATE t1 SET a=IFNULL ( 
    ( SELECT COUNT(b) FROM t2 WHERE c=10 GROUP BY c),0 ) 
WHERE id=20
```

or you can use this if second select result may be empty :

```
UPDATE t1 SET a= if( exists( SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE c=10 GROUP BY c) ) ,(SELECT  COUNT(b) FROM t2 WHERE c=10 GROUP BY c),0)
WHERE id=20
```

Comment: reason i would do this is because, generally, it's not good to rely upon an oddity.  But if it makes you feel like a ninja then niiiiinja-go!

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[COALESCE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)**

```
UPDATE t1
SET a=COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(b) FROM t2 WHERE c=10 GROUP BY c),0)
WHERE id=20
```

**[Refernce](http://www.justskins.com/forums/using-coalesce-for-subqueries-137560.html)**